# Python generator output is entire number instead of digits

Tags: python, generator

I just learnt about generators in Python a week back. From what I understood, the 'yield' returns a generator object instead of the, say, an entire array as is.

Here is the code I wrote for getting the digits of an integer:

```
def getDigits(m):
    for d in str(m):
        yield int(m)
```

This should return the digits of the integer passed to it as a generator object.
But when I do:

```
for i in getDigits(123):
    print i
```

I get the output as:

```
123
123
123
```

instead of:

```
1
2
3
```

What is going on? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please, use the `undersore_separated` function names, not `camelCased`. [PEP8:Function Names](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names)

Comment: do you mean it should be get_Digits() ??
Also, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `yield int(d)` instead of `yield int(m)`:

```
def getDigits(m):
    for d in str(m):
        yield int(d)
```

Comment: i cant accept answer until 20 mins after posting the Q.
accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I think you did mean

```
def getDigits(m):
    for d in str(m):
        yield int(d)
```

i.e. outputting the digit inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Typo:

```
def getDigits(m):
    for d in str(m):
        yield int(d)
```

`d` instead of `m`.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this instead:

```
yield int(d)
```

You are iterating through it but not even using the digit itself.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler form is:

```
getDigits = lammbda m: map(int, str(m))
```